# SQLite transactions resolving before intern calls resolves (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sqlite, async-await

In my React Native app, I'm trying to await for two transactions before performing a query to the database, but I'm having a trouble with async/await.

Simplified code:

```
const loadData = async (data1, data2) => {
    
   await dbInstance.transaction(async tx => {
     console.tron.log('before insert call 1');
     await insertIntoDatabase(dbInstance, 'inventories', data1);
     console.tron.log('after insert call 1');
     Promise.resolve();
   });
        
   await dbInstance.transaction(async tx => {
     console.tron.log('before insert call 2');
     await insertIntoDatabase(dbInstance, 'inventoryDetails', data2);
     console.tron.log('after insert call 2');
     Promise.resolve();
   });
}
```

```
const init = async (data1, data2) => {
   console.log('before loadData');
   await loadData(data1, data2);
   console.log('after loadData')
}
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```
'before loadData'
'before insert call 1'
'after insert call 1'
'before insert call 2'
'after insert call 2'
'after loadData'
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
'before loadData'
'before insert call 1'
'after insert call 1'
'after loadData'
'before insert call 2'
'after insert call 2'
```

Seems that the transactions resolve before hiting `Promise.resolve()`. How can I make them resolve only after the respective `insertIntoDatabase()` call have finished?

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` is doing nothing useful in your code. Which API are you using for database actions?

Comment: I'm using `react-native-sqlite-storage`

Comment: Did you turn on promise mode?

Comment: Yes. It's enough to do it once, right?

Comment: Yes, that is enough, but can you debug and make sure that `dbInstance.transaction(....)` returns a promise object? (so put that result in a variable, **without** `await`, and inspect whether that is a promise object).

Comment: Yes, it does return a Promise.